# A continuous real function $f:[2, \infty] \to \mathbb R$ such that $|f|^p$ is integrable only for a given $p >1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there such a continuous real function $f:[2, \infty] \to \mathbb R$ such that $|f|^p$ is integrable only for a given $p >1$.

My first attempt is to try to look at functions such as $x^{\alpha}(logx)^{\beta}$ which is a typical example of similar questions, but apparently it does not work here.

Comment: you mean Riemann integrable, right? In this case you want to find some function such that $|f|^q$ is unbounded if and only if $q\neq p$, but then $|f|^q$ must be discontinuous.

Comment: @Masacroso This question doesn't really make strict sense in the Riemann setting, you have to go to the improper Riemann setting and it's just kind of a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b>0$. Note that $x^{-1/a} \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$ is in $L^q$ exactly for $q \in [0,a)$. Similarly, $x^{-1/b} \chi_{(1,\infty)}(x)$ is in $L^q$ exactly for $q \in (b,\infty]$. Summing these gives a function in $L^q$ exactly for $q \in [0,a) \cap (b,\infty]=(b,a)$.

Now take your favorite $\epsilon_n \to 0^+$, with $\sup \epsilon_n \leq p$. Take $f_n \in L^q$ for $q \in (p-\epsilon_n,p+\epsilon_n)$ using the construction in the previous paragraph. Then $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{f_n}{\| f_n \|_{L^p}}$ does the job.

This construction is for the domain $(0,\infty)$ or a superset thereof, but it is easy to translate it to any other infinite interval.

This can be adapted to create a function continuous on $[0,\infty)$ including the left endpoint. The second one is easy to deal with, just replace $x^{-1/b} \chi_{(1,\infty)}(x)$ by $\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [0,1] \\ x^{-1/b} & x \not \in [0,1] \end{cases}$. Or you can take pretty much any other bounded, continuous extension.

The first case is not so easy to deal with. Intuitively you need to place spikes that get taller but narrower as $x \to \infty$. Such a spike centered at $0$ looks like $f(x;M,\delta)=\begin{cases} 0 & x \not \in [-\delta,\delta] \\ \frac{M}{\delta}(x+\delta) & x \in [-\delta,0] \\ M-\frac{M}{\delta} x & x \in [0,\delta] \end{cases}$. One can then sum such spikes, centered at, say, $n=0,1,\dots$ for growing $M$ and shrinking $\delta$ to get a function in $L^p$ exactly for $p \in [0,a)$ again. It will help to recall the convergence/divergence behavior of the "$p$ series".

Then you use modifications of these two functions in the same way I suggested in the second paragraph.

Comment: I actually know how to construct one such example for $(0,\infty)$, what really puzzles me is how to translate it to an interval like $[2, \infty)$ while requiring the function to be continuous.

Comment: @koch Do you want it continuous at $2$ as well? That makes things tedious because you have to have successively larger spikes to "kill" the possibility of being in $L^p$ for large $p$. My example can be straightforwardly made continuous away from the left endpoint, but it has to be totally adapted to be continuous at the left endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I do want it to be continuous at $2$. I think it makes the construction harder since the construction  you give does depend on the fact that it is not continuous at endpoints.

Comment: @koch The idea is then very similar to my idea, it is just that you need to cook up a globally continuous function which is only in $L^p$ for small enough $p$, to replace my $x^{-1/a} \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$. Such a function will need to go to zero except for small "spikes" that get taller but narrower as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do you come up with the spikes trick? I generally do not know how to think about such a problem.

Comment: Or can you point out more specifically what do you mean by the convergence behavior of the "p series"?

Comment: @koch The point here is to have the sum of all the spikes have infinite $L^p$ norm for some finite $p$. This happens if the spikes are sufficiently tall. If you accept singularities then this can be done with just one infinite spike, but without singularities you need successively larger finite spikes instead.

Comment: @koch You want $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n^q \delta_n$ to converge for $q<p$ and diverge for $q \geq p$. That's feasible.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Take $f$ that equals $\frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$ on $[n, n+1)$ and $\frac{n}{\log^2 n}$ on $[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$. This will work for only $p=1$. For general $p>0$, take a conveninent power of $f$.

Comment: This is defined on $[0, \infty)$, a minor adjustment will have it on $[2, \infty)$.

Comment: Is it continuous?

Comment: @koch: No. You should interpolate the values with a continuous one. But that is an idea for the scale of decrease ( increase) of $f$.

Comment: @Koch: you can take $f = \frac{1}{x \log^2 x}$ on $[3, \infty)$ and $f=\frac{1}{(x-2) \log^2(x-2)}$ around $2$.

Comment: Except you have a singularity at the left endpoint that can't be mollified away. It is the same concern koch had with my answer.

Comment: @Ian: Oh, i see what the problem is. $f$ has to be bounded on a finite interval. Then the wiggling has to be done only at infinity, basically with the same trick, but we have to mix them together by alternating. Can be done, will leave it here for the OP to do the details.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p>1$, then $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-2)^{1/p}(1+|\log(x-2)|)^{2/p}} \in L^p[2,\infty]$, because
$$\int_{2}^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{(x-2) (1+|ln(x-2)|)^2}=2$$
But $f(x) \notin L^q[2,\infty]$, for $q \neq p$.